# httpclient POST error --- HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: types, media

Does anyone have the experience about HP-IMC API developing ?
i wanna add one customView to IMC server by using script , the following is an example in HP-IMC manual , it describe how to add a device and use POST to do that .

** *start of HP-IMC example*************

Example

Add a custom view named myView. Devices with IDs 1 and 2 are added to the custom view.

Request

POST http://imc.host.net:8080/imcrs/plat/res/view/custom

accept: application/xml

Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8

```
...
<customView>
<name>myView</name>
<device>
<id>1</id>
</device>
<device>
<id>2</id>
</device>
</customView>
```

Response
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Location: http://imc.host.net:8080/imcrs/plat/res/view/custom/1179

******End of HP-IMC example************************

i have no more experience on HTTPclient knowledge , so google some example from internet and modify it as following JAVA code ,
so look at this code below , i want to add a customView named zkmyView into IMC , but it was still "HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type" showed . I don't know whether have some incorrect point in this code ? so does anyone have HP-IMC API coding experience to help me ? Thanks in advance ~

*********************start of my java***************************

public class zk {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String myxml = "<customView><name>zkmyView</name></customView>";
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpContext localcontext = new BasicHttpContext();
    client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope("imc.server.net", 80, "iMC RESTful Web Services"),new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username","password"));
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://imc.host.net:80/imcrs/plat/res/view/custom");

    post.addHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    List<NameValuePair> datatopost = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();


    datatopost.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myxml",myxml));
    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(datatopost));

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post,localcontext);
    System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
    System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));

    }
```

}

***************************end of my java* *******************************